# Replacing Nautilus with Nemo: wallpaper problems

Tags: desktop-background, nemo

I have installed Nemo from the Cinnamon PPA and used the instructions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DefaultFileManager) to set it as the default file manager on my system (Ubuntu Raring). It works perfectly, but causes a strange issue with the system wallpaper.

When I log in, no wallpaper is loaded and the background is simply the remnants of LightDM with the login box etc visible. Only when I open Nemo, close it, and open it one more time does the wallpaper load. I assume this means that Nemo has taken over responsibility for the desktop from Nautilus, but I would like to know how to have it load the wallpaper immediately. Thanks for any help.

Comment: This sounds more like a bug. Have you checked to see if this is a known issue?

Comment: Exactly the same happening here as well. It is really a bug...

Answer (score 2):

For me these steps solved this problem.
Source: http://www.webupd8.org/2012/12/how-to-install-nemo-file-manager-in.html

1. Add `nemo` to Startup Applications, just run the following command:

   `sudo sed -i 's/NoDisplay=true/NoDisplay=false/g' /etc/xdg/autostart/nemo-autostart.desktop`
2. Launch Startup Applications and uncheck Nemo
3. Log out and log back.

Comment: This did not solve the problem for me.  But it was worth a try.

Comment: This just probably just stops it autostarting - it doesn't stop it managing the desktop,,,

Answer (score 1):

For me the solution was to download a package called *compton* which is a lightweight window manager. I put it in my session startup. I got it from this PPA: https://launchpad.net/~richardgv/+archive/compton

I got the idea from this thread about the *nemo* wallpaper issue which suggests a lot of things but *compton* is what finally worked for me: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1328476 I also installed *nitrogen* which is a desktop backgrounds settings tool that is lightweight. I'm not sure if it is required and it didn't work by itself for me. But I need it to change the background as the default gnome one I have doesn't work when I run *nemo*. Note that nitrogen doesn't seem to have any automatically created menu item or icon, I had to launch it from a terminal.

I am using a system which use to be ubuntu lucid with gnome and fancy compiz effects. Then I upgraded to precise with Unity and since I hated that I've slowly been trying to fix the  things that bug me. So, my system is a total mish-mash and YMMV. However, I do think both *nitrogen* and *compton* are lightweight and standalone so hopefully they would work on other setups. And, it didn't require any real hacks :-)